# Can we integrate the radio into EMMS playlist?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The EMMS uses mplayer to play mp3 files in ~/music. It works great. Sometimes we need to use mplayer to listen radio, i.e. "mplayer mms://livexwb.cri.com.cn/am846.wsx > /dev/null".

Can we integrate the radio into EMMS playlist ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 1):

Check out EMMS' streaming audio interface:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/Streaming-Audio.html

Comment: It seems that it doesnot support mms stream as it always report "Invalid URL" when pressing <i> in emms-streams interface.